# How to fetch a specific value in a table based on the range of values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The query below is expected to return 23, but instead throws an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1

```
select brokerage_cost_cad from canada_brokerage_fees 
   where max_merchandise_cost <= 150 
   ORDER BY DESC 
   LIMIT 1;
```

Below is the logic for fetching the brokerage_cost_cad

Rates are as follows, based on the value of the merchandise in CAD:

```
> <=  $40        :  Free
> 40.01 - 150    :  $23.00
> 150.10 - 500   : $24.00
> 500.01 - 1000  : $30.25
> 1000.01 - 1500 : $36.50
> 1500.01 - 2000 : $43.00
> 2000.01 - 2500 : $52.25
> 2500.01 - 3000 : $61.00
> >= 3000.01     : $84.75
```

Table is as the image below shows.

[image]

Comment: There's no column called `max`, and `ORDER BY` requires an expression to order by.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. max needed to be replaced by max_merchandise_cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify any column name in order by clause. After order by and before desc you need to mention the column name. I have added `brokerage_cost_cad` as column name

```
select brokerage_cost_cad from canada_brokerage_fees 
   where max <= 150 
   ORDER BY brokerage_cost_cad  DESC 
   LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: yes, I realize the mistake. Your answer helped.